# How to calculate total disk size in Linux?

Tags: linux

LIke df -h gives following output:

```
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv       15G  9.9G  4.8G  68% /
devtmpfs                         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            16G   12K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            16G  1.2G   15G   8% /run
tmpfs                            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                       488M  178M  275M  40% /boot
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp_lv       8.8G   52M  8.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/rootvg-opt_lv        18G   12G  6.1G  67% /opt/wildfly
/dev/mapper/rootvg-keycloak_lv  4.8G  1.1G  3.6G  23% /opt/keycloak
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var_lv        25G   23G  2.1G  92% /var
/dev/mapper/rootvg-data_lv       50G  970M   46G   3% /data
/dev/mapper/rootvg-home_lv      997M  475M  523M  48% /home
/dev/mapper/rootvg-doc_lv        20G  9.9G  9.7G  51% /var/lib/docker
146.213.179.242:/test01         228G   93G  136G  41% /shared
```

So Total disk size will be sum of second columns (Excluding last row)? i.e

```
  Size 
   15G 
   16G 
   16G 
   16G 
   16G 
  488M 
  8.8G 
   18G 
  4.8G 
   25G 
   50G 
  997M 
   20G
```

Is there some other space which is hidden? No Command gives total size but bifurcate on filesystems? I want to write Java program based on same.

Comment: Try `cat /proc/partitions`.

Comment: It is not in readable format.

major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  104857600 sda
   8        1     524288 sda1
   8        2  104332288 sda2
   8       16   31457280 sdb
   8       32   20971520 sdc
  11        0    1048575 sr0
 253        0   15360000 dm-0
 253        1    2097152 dm-1
 253        2    9216000 dm-2
 253        3   26210304 dm-3
 253        4    1024000 dm-4
 253        5   19202048 dm-5
 253        6   20971520 dm-6
 253        7    5242880 dm-7
 253        8   52428800 dm-8

Comment: Are you looking for `fdisk -l` ?

Comment: Also note you probably want to exclude the `tmpfs` partitions as they aren't backed by a local disk.

Comment: What happened to 228G ? Is it not disc? Why are you counting tmpfs as a disc? How is exactly "total disc size" defined?

Comment: @SamMason: so other then tmpfs, i got the actual size?

Comment: @KamilCuk: It is some shared disc. Total disc size, i am trying to find... i m getting partitions only

Comment: @Fryz: nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would output **block devices** there are discs using `lsblk` and sum the size of them:

```
$ lsblk -rbo TYPE,SIZE | awk '$1=="disk"{sum+=$2} END{print sum}' | numfmt --to=si
1.2T
```

`df` prints you **mount points** not necessarily block devices, like `tmpfs` is temporary file system.

Comment: Not working for me. It show help menu

Comment: When lsblk, i get (shortened)

[wildfly@alq-esb-app03 log]$ lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                      8:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─sda1                   8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                   8:2    0 99.5G  0 part
  ├─rootvg-root_lv     253:0    0  8.9G  0 lvm  /
  ├─rootvg-swap_lv     253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]

sdb                      8:16   0   30G  0 disk
├─rootvg-root_lv       253:0    0  8.9G  0 lvm  /
sr0                     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

Comment: `It show help menu` what is "it"? does "it" show _an error message_? Wwhat is the output of `lsblk --version`? I have `lsblk from util-linux 2.38.1`. I believe the code I presented should be enough for you to write your own. See `lsblk --help` for explanation of options, even with no options, you can still parse with `awk` everything anyway.

Comment: lsblk from util-linux 2.23.2

Comment: lsblk: invalid option -- 'M'

Comment: so remove that option..........

Comment: lsblk -rbo TYPE,SIZE | awk '$1=="disk"{sum+=$2} END{print sum}' | numfmt --to=si1.2T  ..............
numfmt: invalid argument ‘si1.2T’ for ‘--to’

Comment: lsblk -rbo TYPE,SIZE | awk '$1=="disk"{sum+=$2} END{print sum}' | numfmt --to=si
140G